# Answers (not solutions) to Exercises in Textbook " Algebra" by Thomas Hungerford

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, galois-theory, book-recommendation

I am self studying for an exam in algebra from Textbook "Algebra" by Thomas Hungerford and I try exercise problems . Some of them are about determining a group or field and as I checked it comes without any answers to those questions.

It is not possible to type every such  question here for verification. So, can you please tell if any solution to my problem as sometimes despite best of effort and no matter how clear any student's concepts are there could be mistakes which lead to difference of answer without his/her  realization that he is wrong.

If someone knows of any institute that run a webpage (due to offering of problems from Hungerford)? More precisely, I am interested in answers to problems from Section: Fields and Galois Theory as of now.

Or there is some other solution of my problem ?

I hope this question is not off-topic here!

Comment: Yes, there is some other solution of your problem. This site has already discussed $99\%$ of these exercises here as posts, with many excellent answers. It is worth to read these posts here. I know, writing a post is quicker than reading a post, but it will certainly pay off.

Comment: Seconding Dietrich's advice. The on-site search is anything but perfect, but it is still useful. For example searching for *Hungerford* within the tag [tag:abstract-algebra] gives you [this list](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Babstract-algebra%5D+Hungerford), where you can further refine the search. Presumably your questions at a given time in near future will revolve around a specific theme, and you can use relevant tags as extras.

Comment: Apparently you are starting with Galois theory. You can also search for a specific polynomial (or something close to it). The on-site search does not grok TeX, so it is not very good there. Thankfully we have [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E4-x-1%24&p=2) (that link searches for occurrences of $x^4-x-1$, you can edit it to match your needs).